# How to get scope of grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am creating a grid inside one penal. Now I wanted to access this grid and for that I am writing a function.
which is like this.

```
function getGrid(obj, store){
debugger;
}
```

Here obj is grid and store is store.
But I don't know where to write. How to get the correct scope.

my Store and Grid code is

```
initComponent:function(){
            var myData = [       
                            ['FFPE Slide',2,'eSample'],
                            ['Plasma',2,'eSample'],
                            ['Whole Blood',2,'eSample']
                        ];   

                            // create the data store
            var myStor = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                        fields: [
                            {name: 'Stu'},
                            {name: 'Sub'},
                            {name: 'Excl'}
                            ]
                         });

                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    region:"east",
                    header:true,
                    collapsible:true,
                    autoScroll:true,
                    width:"30%",
                    hideBorders:true,                   
                    split:true,
                    items: [{
                            xtype:'panel',
                            title:"Panel Header",
                            items:[],
                            id:'East_pan',
                            tbar: this.desToolbar
                        },{
                            xtype:'panel',
                            title:"Result",
                            items:[{
                                    xtype :'grid',
                                    id: 'COHART_GRID',
                                    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
                                    frame: true,
                                    store: myStor,
                                    autoHeight: true,
                                    stripeRows: true,
                                    columns: [
                                        {
                                        text: 'Study',
                                        id: 'Sd', 
                                        header: 'Study',
                                        width: 130,
                                        sortable: false,
                                        hideable: false,
                                        dataIndex: 'Stu'
                                        },
                                        {
                                        text: 'Subject',
                                        width: 130,
                                        header: 'Subject',
                                        id:'Sub',
                                        dataIndex: 'Sub',
                                        hidden:false,
                                        },
                                        {
                                        text: 'Exclude',
                                        width: 130,
                                        id:'Ext',
                                        header: 'Exclude',
                                        dataIndex: 'Excl',
                                        hidden:false
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }]

                        }]
                    }
            }
```

Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the **grid** using `getCmp` function & after getting the grid you can call `getStore` on it to get its **store**:

```
var obj=Ext.getCmp('COHART_GRID');
var store=obj.getStore();
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But here  I am not getting getColumnManager() function. Any Idea ?

Comment: Are you using ExtJs 3?

Comment: It don't support `getColumnManager()`.You can use `columns` if you want to just get the columns

Answer (score 1):

1) Dont Use getCmp() use Component query.

2) Change id to itemID in the Grid declaration.

```
                            xtype :'grid',
                            itemId: 'COHART_GRID',
                            selType: 'checkboxmodel',
                            frame: true,
                            store: myStor,
                            autoHeight: true,
                            stripeRows: true,
```

3) store = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#COHART_GRID')[0].getStore().
4) can you access your grid and Store in the Controller.

Comment: Thanks. BUt Here I am not getting getColumnManager() function.